# I can see the uncommited changes after I checkout to an earlier commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a repository, it has two files: `file1` and `file2`.

I make changes to `file2`, add only `file2` to staging area and do a commit.

Then I make changes to `file1` but I didn't add it to staging area or commit the changes.

Now I do checkout to an earlier commit.

`file2`'s changes are not shown after the checkout.

But I can see the changes of `file1`.

Shouldn't all the files in the repository be reverted back to the state of earlier commit after I do a checkout?

Please provide an explanation on why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is expected.

Uncommitted changes are kept in the working tree as long as they don't conflict with the state of the files you're checking out.

If they *would* conflict, or if your uncommitted changes would be erased by checking out, git outputs a warning and cancels the operation.

---

As a sidenote, and on a practical level, if you need to inspect an earlier commit despite having uncommited changes in the working tree, you can [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your changes for later, check out what you wanted, then recover your stash if needed.

Comment: As @RomainValeri wrote when you change branches or checkout to somewhere the changes that are not committed come with you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I want to understand why this happens? doesn't git track the status of all the files in repository when we make a commit? isn't the purpose of checkout is to take all files to certain version at a point of time?

Comment: @sai Yes it is, but if you don't add/commit a file, you don't make git aware of it, so you can't expect it to be known later. Committing is the process of putting some new change in the history tree. After your checkout, the working tree reflects that commit, but on top of that you keep the uncommitted changes you had.